# OSX / Emacs -- arrow key navigation of directory tree for open / save of file

Tags: emacs

Is it possible to use the arrow keys to navigate the directory tree when opening / saving a file in OSX (Mountain Lion)?  I would prefer not to use the mouse, or type the name of the folder.  The arrow keys have no effect, except for command+up/down.

I've tried a couple of different OSX versions of Emacs, and haven't figured out how to do this.

Comment: It looks like the nightly build that was just released for Aquamacs 24.3.50.3 fixes this issue.

Comment: I'm still looking for a resolution; however, as to a current Emacs version (24.3) built from source with the option `./configure --with-ns`.  The nightly builds of Aquamacs are only alpha / beta working drafts, and are not yet stable enough to use reliably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I communicated this bug to the developers, and they quickly responded by stating that this bug was addressed already in the developer build of emacs-trunk.  I have since built a developer build of eacs-trunk and have verified that the bug is fixed -- it will be available as part of the next major release, or for anyone who wants to use a nightly build.  The nighty build of Aquamacs has already merged this bug fix from the emacs-trunk.